# How to insert polyline on ArcGIS JavaScript 3.x?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using JavaScript 3.x library of ArcGIS for plotting the polyline but nothing to show on the map.

```
 function simtest() {
                 var p1 = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Point(76.331549,10.013566, new SpatialReference({
                                wkid: 4326
                            })));
var p2 = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Point(76.331463,10.013566, new SpatialReference({
                                wkid: 4326
                            })));
line = new esri.geometry.Polyline();
line.addPath([p1, p2]);
polygraphlayer.add(new esri.Graphic(
  line,

  new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
                    esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new dojo.Color([124,252,0, 0.1]), 2)
));
var pt = new Point(76.331549,10.013566, new SpatialReference({
                                wkid: 4326
                            }));

 map.centerAndZoom(pt,13);


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a working example base on you code with a few fixes, I change one the points coordinates to make the polyline visible to the zoom level you choose (just to avoid zooming in).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Create Polylines</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;    
      require([
        "dojo/_base/Color",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/geometry/Polyline", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils", 
        "esri/graphic", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", "esri/SpatialReference",
        "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Color,
        Map, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Polyline,
        SimpleLineSymbol, webMercatorUtils,
        Graphic, GraphicsLayer, SpatialReference,
        dom, domAttr
      ) {
        var symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(
          SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new Color([255, 0, 0, 1]),
          2
        );
        var sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
          .setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE)
          .setColor(new Color([255,0,0,0.5])
        );
        var gl = new GraphicsLayer({ id: "graphics" });
        function simtest() {
          var p1 = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(
            new Point(
              76.381549,
              10.013566,
              new SpatialReference({
                wkid: 4326
              })
            )
          );
          var p2 = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(
            new Point(
              76.331463,
              10.013566,
              new SpatialReference({
                wkid: 4326
              })
            )
          );
          var line = new esri.geometry.Polyline(p2.spatialReference);
          line.addPath([p1, p2]);
          gl.add(
            new esri.Graphic(
              line,
              symbol
            )
          );
          gl.add(
            new esri.Graphic(
              p1,
              sms
            )
          );
          gl.add(
            new esri.Graphic(
              p2,
              sms
            )
          );
          var pt = new Point(
            76.331549,
            10.013566,
            new SpatialReference({
              wkid: 4326
            })
          );
          map.centerAndZoom(pt,13);
        }
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-120.741, 56.39],
          slider: false,
          zoom: 6
        });
        map.addLayer(gl);
        simtest();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```